# How can I get all current lines on pty terminal

Tags: bash, go, terminal, pty

I am running bash commands with pty.

```
cmd := exec.Command("/bin/bash", []string{}...)
ptyIo, err := pty.Start(cmd)
```

I can resize pty window, write bytes, read bytes with a loop (It gives changes on terminal).

I am using "github.com/kr/pty" pty library.

How can I get all current lines on the terminal screen whenever I want?

Comment: There's no way to get window content via the tty interface.

Comment: If you run commands from w/in tmux, there's probably a way to do what you want.